# Range copy script only works for the first row of a multi-row range

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I adapted a Google Apps Script from [@Diego's Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51321896/). The script moves the contents of a range to a new location.

The only modifications I made to the script was to remove the line `source.clear()` in order to have the script perform a copy instead of a cut, and I changed the sheet  references to match my own.

The problem is that when the source range includes multiple rows, only the first row is copied to the destination.

How can I get the script to include all the rows?

```
function moveValuesOnly() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var source = ss.getRange("RUNSHEET!H4:AC20");
   var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("RUNSHEET");
   destSheet.appendRow(source.getValues()[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove

```
destSheet.appendRow(source.getValues()[0]);
```

by something else because

`appendRow` only adds one row of values

and

```
source.getValues()[0]
```

returns only the values of first row of `source`

That something else could be one of the methods `getRange` and then `setValues(source.getValues())` or you could use `copyTo`

There are a lot of examples on this site.

- [How to copy range from last row to a new row created via script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/99167/88163)
- [Variables in Google getRange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/137929/88163)

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Answer (score 0):

Replacing [@Diego's scrip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51321896/) with the script from the original question, ["Copying and Paste Values into next empty Row in Google Sheets"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51317740), resolved the problem.

The only modifications I made to the script from the question were:

1. I updated the references to match my own.
2. To preserve the original content (copy instead of cut), I removed the following line:

> ```
> source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
> ```

#### Updated Script

```
function moveValuesOnly () {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
    var source = ss.getRange ("Runsheet!H4:AB24");
    var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("RunsheetData");
    var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);
    source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

Comment: I guess one person's problem is another person's solution (and vice versa) 